# Agregar subfijo a firma electronica

Tags: c#

Amigos como estan, estoy tratando de hacer el firmado de un xml con un archivo de firma .pfx, el archivo tiene que ser firmado  con las extensiones Xades-Bes y firmas tipo RSA con algoritmo SHA-256.

Tengo que obtener una firma parecida a la siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente

```
  public void Firmar()
{
    string archivoFirma = @"C:\archivos\firma.pfx";
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(archivoFirma, "ClaveFirma", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    xmlDoc.Load(@"c:\archivos\FA076.xml");
    SignXml(xmlDoc, cert);
    xmlDoc.Save(@"c:\archivos\FA076Firmado.xml");
}

public void SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    if (xmlDoc == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
    if (cert == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Cert");

    var exportedKeyMaterial = cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString( /* includePrivateParameters = */ true);
    var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(24 /* PROV_RSA_AES */));
    key.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    key.FromXmlString(exportedKeyMaterial);

    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
    signedXml.SigningKey = key;
    signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

    Reference reference = new Reference();
    reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
    reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
    reference.Uri = ""; 
    signedXml.AddReference(reference);

    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));
    signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

    signedXml.ComputeSignature();
    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

}
```

Pero en veo que en la firma de falta los subfijos ds:, por ejemplo.

Entonces queria saber como puedo hacer que el procedo de firmado agregue estos subfijos?